# How to write code for allow only two digit after period using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

i have to enter only two digit after dot.
for example
23.34
1.22
.23

Here is sample code

```
<input type="text" id="amount" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(this);"> 

function isNumberKey(evt) 
{ 
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode; 
    return (charCode<=31 ||  charCode==46 || (charCode>=48 && charCode<=57)); 
} 

function validCurrency(amt) 
{ 
    return amt.match(/^\d*(.\d{0,2})?$/); 
}
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following regex:

```
/^\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?$/
```

The main mistake you were making was not escaping dot with a backslash. The dot would accept any character. Dot escaped with a backslash would look for a dot, and not any character.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```
/.*\.\d\d$/
```

It will match:

```
anything                .*
followed by a dot       \.
followed by two digits  \d\d
anchored to the end     $
```

Here it is with your function:

```
function validCurrency(amt) 
{ 
    return amt.match(//.*\.\d\d/$/); 
}
```